# Javascript not working on page

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get my javascript to work on my page, the same code works on another page, but not the one i'm using currently. the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            var $scores = $("#usersload");
            setInterval(function () {
                $scores.load("users.php #usersload");
            }, 15000);
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>
```

The above code should refresh a div on the page every 15 seconds, when the page loads, but does nothing, but on my other page it does what its suppose to.

if you need more code from my page let me know, but if you can help, thanks in advance!

Javascript on page:

```
<script>var init = [];</script>

    <!-- Get jQuery from Google CDN -->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">'+"<"+"/script>"); </script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Pixel Admin's javascripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js?parameter=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/pixel-admin.min.js?parameter=1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    init.push(function () {
        // Javascript code here
    });
    window.PixelAdmin.start(init);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            var $scores = $("#usersload");
      setInterval(function () {
          $scores.load("users.php #usersload");
      }, 15000);
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>
```

Comment: If the only difference is that it's on another page, could the issue be the path - `users.php`?

Comment: try <script type="text/javascript">
        alert();
    </script>
to see if this snipet works

Comment: users.php is the page that the code is on, its just refreshing a div inside the page, users.php is in the same directory.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> alert(); </script>` works.

Comment: You missing a `<script>` tag at the start `src="https://aj...`should be `<script src="https://aj...`.

Comment: Also can you show what users.php is sending as a response please?

Comment: I put the code at the bottom, it works now, but now the jquery isn't working on the page.

Comment: Your second bit of code will not work because you are defining `init` after you are using it.

Comment: What should I do to fix it then?

Comment: @keizom what should I do to fix it?

Comment: @keizom `var init = [];` is on the top of the body, while `.push()` is at the bottom of the body.

Comment: @Melternet It wasn't like that when keizom commented. What error message are you getting?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek am I able to post my whole source code of the users.php here?

Comment: @Melternet You mentioned the problem is with your JavaScript and not with your PHP file. If the PHP file isn't relevant to your problem don't post it. If there is an error in your PHP file than you should post it, and mention any errors you are getting.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I can't check the errors seeming the server is hosted, but I got the script to work, but now my jquery isn't working anymore, but when i remove the script it starts to work once again.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible.

Have you added jQuery to the page yet, before this script block ofcourse.

The simplest way to do so..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this on y page and this works

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function call(){
        var $scores = $("#usersload");
        $.post('user.php',{blankpost:''}, function(result){
            $scores.html(result);
        });
    }
    function codeAddress() {
            setInterval( function(){
              call();
            }, 1000);
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress();
</script>
```

the blank post is ust to post something on the page, and just display the result

Comment: first how do I get the full path to page, and second I want to refresh part of the page not the whole thing...

Comment: I was finding that weird also to get the whole page loading. You can do a ajax call or a $.post request, and fetch the result to the div

Comment: I did, but thing is, the script I have works, but now my jquery doesn't, not sure why.

Comment: maybe you have a script containing a fatal error thus stopping the whole script. What does your console says?

Comment: I don't have access to my console.

Comment: ctrl+shift+i on chrome (or yandex)

Answer (score 0):

On the last line of your code, you have:

window.onload = codeAddress;

With that being said, shouldn't you still have to pass it an empty parameter such as the following?

window.onload = codeAddress();